# rsync wildcard not working in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, wildcard, rsync, raspberry-pi3

I try to sync files via `rsync` to my `raspberry pi 3`.

```
rsync -v -P -r --size-only --remove-source-files /home/user*.mp3 osmc@192.168.0.110:/media/hdd/
```

This command works fine and only copies the `mp3` files.

Since files are not all in the same place, and i don't want to type the command all the time, i did a `bash` script so i could change the path to source and destination.

```
echo "ENTER PATH" 
read -i "/home/user/*.mp3" -e path

echo "ENTER DESTINATION!"
read -i "osmc@192.168.0.110:/media/hdd/" -e dest

rsync -v -P -r --size-only --remove-source-files "$path" "$dest"
```

But this gives me the following error message

```
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/*.mp3" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

If i do `"/home/user/"` the script is working, but copies all files not only `mp3`. So i guess the wildcard is not working in this `bash` script

Any clue why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an `rsync` wildcard but a `bash` wildcard, aka glob. Bash will replace it with a list of files before `rsync` is ever called.

However, bash doesn't do word splitting and globbing on quoted variables:

```
var="/etc/*tab"
echo "Quoted:" "$var"
echo "Unquoted:" $var
```

Results in:

```
Quoted: /etc/*tab
Unquoted: /etc/crontab /etc/fstab /etc/inittab /etc/mtab
```

You don't normally want bash to mess around with your variables, which is why quoting is so important and kudos for doing it. However, in this case you actually *do* want pathname expansion, so you should carefully leave the variable unquoted:

```
# Prevent word splitting, so that '/path with spaces/*.mp3' still works
IFS="" 
# No quoting on $path, to allow glob expansion:
rsync -v -P -r --size-only --remove-source-files $path "$dest"
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. Did not know that it could be such an easy solution. Again, thank you, very much appreciated.